# Skip Unique key violations for INSERTing all records which are ok

Tags: postgresql

In the Postgres table, I have a primary key (Auto gen) and a unique constraint in addition.

Currently: While INSERTING using a SELECT statement,if a duplicate (unique constraint) is violated, then it does not INSERT anything at all.

Requirement: If any Dupicate occur, it should SKIP those records, catch them in a temp table, and continue INSERTING all the records which are ok (without constraint issues)

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_output (
    id SERIAL,
    title TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    description TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT Invoice_pk PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT title_unique UNIQUE(title)
);
```

Calling a function to do the Insert as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fn_create_invoice_output(<params>)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
...

BEGIN
  INSERT INTO public.invoice_output(id,title,description)
  SELECT id,title,description FROM public.invoice_input;

    IF NOT FOUND THEN
      RAISE WARNING  'fn_create_invoice_header_output() - job id or client not found';
      status := -1;
    END IF;

   RETURN status;

END;

$function$
;
```

I am getting SQL Error [23505]: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint.

How can I make an exception such that only non duplicates are inserted and committed. and the keys for duplicates can be skipped from insert, captured and printed out

I have tried this after my insert statement

```
EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN RAISE NOTICE 'row skipped in  public.fn_create_invoice_output ';
```

Or can we Iterate through result set of select statement for the insert command and then it will be easy to do so?

Comment: You should take a look on https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ON CONFLICT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT):

```
INSERT INTO public.invoice_output (id,title,description)
SELECT id,title,description 
FROM public.invoice_input
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Comment: Unfortunately ON CONFLICT is limited to either skip the row (with no indication of doing so) or updating current values (also with no indication of doing so), but you cannot "captured and printed out" or log as you want. For that you can iterate a cursor and capture each exception or a preemptive logging of existing rows by selecting only those that already exist. Then modify insert-select to get only rows that do not exist. Either way you pay for the logging in performance. Your question: Is it worth the cost? If not just stick with on conflict do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the CONFLICT clause as:

```
INSERT INTO public.invoice_output (id, title, description)
    SELECT id, title, description FROM public.invoice_input
    ON CONFLICT (id) DO NOTHING;
```

Ref: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT